# Java: Why is the parent class methods visible to the derived class?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods, java-8

```
 class Base {
    public void display(int n){ 
        System.out.println(n); 
        
    }}
 class Derived extends Base{ 
    public void display(){ //Line-1 
        System.out.println("display overloaded"); 
            
        }}
public class Tester { 
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        Derived ref = new Derived(); 
        ref.display(10); //Line-2 
                }}
```

Why does this code work?How is the parent class methods visible and available to the child class? Shouldn't line 2 throws an error saying that there is no such method or that the method defined shouldn't have any parameters.

Comment: You are not *overriding*. You are *overloading*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java all the methods and variables with `public` and `protected` access modifiers are inherited from Parent class to Child class. Due that your display method with input parameter as int `display(int n)` is also inherited from parent class `Base` to `Derived`. Resulting method will be available to base class as well.

And when you create display method in your `Derived` class with no parameter `display()`, you are actually using method overloading concept (not overriding). So in your `Derived` class, actually you have two methods with same name (different argument) `display()` and `display(int n)`.

And that's why you are not getting **no such method or that the method defined shouldn't have any parameters**.

Answer (score 3):

Those are different methods, to override a method you must have the same method signature

```
@Override
public void display(int n){ 
  System.out.println("display overloaded"); 
}
```

Add also `@Override` to indicate you are overriding base method

Notice you can't really delete a method, just override it (or overload as your example)

Answer (score 0):

The method derived is overriding the method in its superclass but it is not taking any argument but you gave an argument to your child class derived so it finds which method is taking an argument and it finds so that's why it is not giving an error